# In PiSimpleGUI: I want 2 dropdown menus and submit button to interact. After picking something from drop1, and then drop2, And then click submit

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, interaction, pysimplegui

```py
dropdown1 = [[sg.Combo(['Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3'], default_value='Choice 1', enable_events=True, 
             key='drop1')]]

dropdown2= [[sg.Combo(['Choice A', 'Choice B', 'Choice C'], default_value='Choice A', enable_events=True, 
             key='drop2')]]

layout = [[sg.Column(dropdown1), sg.Column(dropdown2), sg.Button('Submit', enable_events = True, 
          key='Submit')]]

window = sg.Window('window',layout)

def choice1_choiceA():
    print('you chose 1 and A')

def choice1_choiceB():
    print('you chose 1 and B')

def choice1_choiceC():
    print('you chose 1 and C')

def other_choicecombos:
    print('etc')


while True:
     
     event, values = window.read()
     
     if event == ***choice 1*** and event == ***choice A*** and event =='Submit':
    
        choice1_choiceA
     
    if event == ***choice 1*** and event == ***choice B*** and event == 'Submit':
    
        choice1_choiceB

#### and so on and so forth for the rest of the options. I just don't know how to make it do this. I'm a novice programmer.

window.close()
```

Comment: I have tried this here:
if event == values('drop1'[0]) and event == values('drop2'[0]) and event == 'Submit':

        choice1_choiceA()

and get an error :

TypeError:  'dict' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Here, you don't need to care events from `'drop1'` and `'drop2'`, but event from `'Sumbit'`.

Here for the event loop

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        choice = values['drop1'], values['drop2']
        if choice == ("Choice 1", "Choice A"):
            choice1_choiceA()
        elif choice == ("Choice 1", "Choice B"):
            choice1_choiceB()
        elif choice == ("Choice 1", "Choice C"):
            choice1_choiceC()
        else:
            other_choicecombos()

window.close()
```

or just like this one,

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Submit':
        choice1, choice2 = values['drop1'], values['drop2']
        print(f"You chose '{choice1.split()[1]}' and '{choice2.split()[1]}'")

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Yang. I have to do a bunch of tedious additions to the actual functions in my programs but I do believe this line of logic will work since it worked in the example program. Thank you really this place is such a help.